# undefined method `-' for "books, children":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags, acts-as-taggable

PROBLEM -- undefined method `-' for "books, children":String

The 'acts_as_taggable_on_steroids' has not been maintained for some time now. It used to work very well until recently. Now when I try to create or update tags, I get an error message --> 
        undefined method `-' for "books, children":String

```
                  --- Codings ----
```

acts_as_taggable.rb

```
   1. module ActiveRecord #:nodoc:
   2. module Acts #:nodoc:
   3.  module Taggable #:nodoc:
   4.    def self.included(base)
   5.  base.extend(ClassMethods)
   6. end


   7. module ClassMethods

   8.  def acts_as_taggable
   9.   has_many :taggings, :as => :taggable, :dependent => :destroy
   10.  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings

   11. before_save :save_cached_tag_list

   12. after_create :save_tags  
   13. after_update :save_tags   

   14.  include ActiveRecord::Acts::Taggable::InstanceMethods
   15. extend ActiveRecord::Acts::Taggable::SingletonMethods

   16. alias_method_chain :reload, :tag_list
```

::::::::::::::::::::::::

```
   17. def save_tags
   18.       return unless @tag_list

   19.     new_tag_names = @tag_list - tags.map(&:name)
   20.   old_tags = tags.reject { |tag| @tag_list.include?(tag.name) }

   21. self.class.transaction do
   22.  if old_tags.any?
   23.  taggings.find(:all, :conditions => ["tag_id IN (?)", 
   24. old_tags.map(&:id)]).each(&:destroy)
   25.       taggings.reset
   26.    end

   27.  new_tag_names.each do |new_tag_name|
   28.  tags << Tag.find_or_create_by_name(new_tag_name)
   29. end

   30.  end

   31.  true
   32. end
   33.  end
```

Note: The line 19 causes the problem!

tag.rb

```
    1. class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    2. attr_accessible :name
    3.  has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy
    4.  validates :name, :presence=>true
    5. validates_uniqueness_of :name
    6.  def self.find_or_create_by_name(name)
    7.  Tag.where(:name=>name).first_or_create do |tag|
    8.  tag.name = name
    9. end
    10. end
```

Any help would be appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where is `@tag_list` created?  It seems that it used to be an array and now it's a string

If you want a quick fix you could change line 19 to this:

```
new_tag_names = @tag_list.split(', ') - tags.map(&:name)
```

Comment: did it error out in another place or the same one?  probably you can change the way that `@tag_list` is created so it makes an array - if you change it at the source you should be okay.

Comment: I followed your advice and did few re-adjustments to my view and model files and it works so far.I will do the further testing just in case.